# Create a new df column based on two existing columns

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame that has two columns: 'Sex' (possible values M and F) and 'IsChild' possible values (True or False). What is the most efficient way to create a new column that takes on values (Child,Male,Female) based on values of Sex and IsChild?

Comment: what is the value of the column in case of child=True in sex=female? should it return "child" if child==true, and only if child==false the return sex?

Comment: yes only return child if child is True otherwise return sex

Answer (score 0):

For this simple condition, following code will work:

```py
df.loc[df["Child"]==True, "new_col"] = "Child"
df.loc[df["Child"]==False, "new_col"] = df["Sex"]
```

At first line: `df.loc` takes only some rows, based on condition, for which I assign "Child" value. The condition in our case is `df["Child"]==True`.

The second line does kinda the same. It updates only where `df["Child"]==false`.

You can then use`.map` to replace values (M to Male for example)

If your condition was more complex, you can use `apply` function: it works on every row separately. You could write an auxiliary function that returns whatever your want based on your conditions, and then use apply to call to this function on every row.